# Xamarin.Forms.FlexLayout - how do left justify last row

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using the FlexLayout with images. My last row contains an odd number of images. How can I left justify the last row images?  Currently they appear centered.

```
 <FlexLayout x:Name="ThumbnailLayout"
     AlignItems="Start"
     JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly"
     Wrap="Wrap">
    </FlexLayout>
```

See attachment..
thx[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOTdh.png)

Comment: <FlexLayout AlignItems=" Direction=" JustifyContent=" Wrap="Wrap">   **Set** this type **JustifyContent="Start"** .is it work

Comment: It aligns to left.. which is good.. but then I have white space down the right side. Need it spaced across evenly, but 'START'ing on the left.   thx

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you should be able to do that, however I ran into the same issue. I solved my situation by setting the FlexLayout.Basis attribute on the ImageButton inside of the FlexLayout, setting JustifyContent="Start" and giving it a HeightRequest.

```
<FlexLayout x:Name="photos" JustifyContent="Start" Wrap="Wrap">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ImageButton
                   FlexLayout.Basis="33.33%"
                      x:Name="imageCell"
                      Aspect="AspectFill"
                      Clicked="ImageClicked"
                      Source="{Binding ThumbnailSource}"
                      >
                    <ImageButton.HeightRequest>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Phone="110" Tablet="180"/>
                    </ImageButton.HeightRequest>
                </ImageButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </FlexLayout>
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution but it removes the wrapping feature of the items and fix the number of items in each row to be 3 (33.33% of the view)